# A question of vectorial subspace, base and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have this question to answer, but I'm having some problems to find the resolution to get the answer. I will be very grateful if someone helps :D.

Consider the real vector space $V=\mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{R})$, provided with the usual operations with polynomials. we have $W=\{p\in V : p(1)+p(0)=0\}$, it is asked:

(A) Show that the W is a vector subspace of V.

(B) Find a basis for the vector subspace W, justifying the answer.

(C) With respect to item (B), give the dimension of the vector subspace W.

Comment: i opened the vector first $ W = (\alpha_0, -\alpha_0, \alpha_2 p_2, \alpha_3 p_3)$.

Comment: then i multiply for a constant and equals to 0. $$-Y\alpha_0=0$$ $$X\alpha_0=0$$ $$Z\alpha_2 p_2=0$$ $$t\alpha_3 p_3 + t\alpha_2 p_2 = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

A) there are 8 axioms that must hold to show that $W$ is a vector space.
i.e. show that $W$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

B) If $p(x)$ is a polynomial in $W$ what are it roots?
Can you find one example of a member of $W.$  Can you generalize from there?

C) If you have your basis, how many independent vectors spans the space?

Answer (score 0):

**hint for B**

The polynom $P=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d $ is in $W  \iff $

$$P (0)+P (1)=0 \iff $$
$$d+a+b+c+d=0 \iff $$
$$a=-2d-b-c. $$

$$\iff P=b (x^2-x^3)+c (x-x^3)+d (1-2x^3) $$
$$=bP_1 (x)+cP_2 (x)+dP_3 (x) $$

thus $$W=span (P_1 (x),P_2 (x),P_3 (x)) $$
Prove the three polynoms are independent.
You can take it.

Comment: ok thank you, i get it